# How to remove lines in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In microsoft word 2007 it is easy to make a line seperate by typing 3 dashes and pressing enter, like so

```
---
```

Normally I have no trouble removing these line seperates, but at the moment I have one I can't delete. I can't right click on it or anything, and even after deleting all of the text it remains.

How can I remove this thing, and why is it so hard to remove?

Comment: I doubt it would have helped in this situation, but sometimes it helps to select (and delete) the paragraph mark (the [pilcrow ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow), ¶) which you can toggle using Ctrl-* (hence: Ctrl-Shift-8 on most keyboards). Like, if a bullet is styled differently from the sentence that follows it, that formatting is also set on the ¶ of the sentence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, so even if you do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all content in Word, then press <kbd>del</kbd> to delete, the divider is *still* present?

I did some testing and this isn't a horizontal line (oddly enough), when you type

```
---
```

You get a **bottom-border**, which you can turn off via the Home, Paragraph, Borders control:

[image]

Comment: If I select the entire document and press delete then it does indeed disappear, but if I select the text on either side of the border so as to include it, and delete the section containing it it wont delete. I always used --- as a quick separator and had no idea it was a border...explains why I could not delete it. Your solution worked perfectly, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Highlight all texts with the lines (or just over near the line if there's only one line), then click the border icon from the menu and select 'No Border'

If you select 'Bottom Border' you'll still see a dotted line. And if copy the text and paste elsewhere, the dotted line would still be there.